# How to concatenate vector of integers interleaving elements with a character?

Tags: r, concatenation

I would like to turn vector

```
a <- 1:5
```

into a string

```
"1_2_3_4_5"
```

How to do this?

```
paste(a,sep="_")
```

does not work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `collapse`

```
paste(a, collapse="_")
#[1] "1_2_3_4_5"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
paste0(a, collapse="_")
# [1] "1_2_3_4_5"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
 gsub(', ', '_', toString(a))
 #[1] "1_2_3_4_5"
```